# How to change color of a svg image from encoded url?

Tags: html, css, xml, image, svg

I have an image URL that is basically a svg image.

`data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<?xml%20version="1.0"%20encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE%20svg%20PUBLIC%20"-//W3C//DTD%20SVG%201.1//EN"%20"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg%20xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"%20width="14"%20height="12"%20version="1"><path%20color="%23FF0000"%20d="M4%208L0%204h8z"/></svg>`

[image: Added red color but is shows black]

I tried changing the color but it doesn't work.

Can you suggest any alternate way or fix the URL?

Comment: edit the URL and change %23FF0000 to whatever colour you want. Note that SVG colours are determined by the fill and stroke properties and not the color property so you'll have to fix that too.

Comment: Tried but it does not work.

Comment: You're also using the wrong property for SVG, color does nothing there. I suggest fixing the SVG before trying to use it as a data URI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fill` property as used here:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="12" version="1">
    <path color="#FF0000" d="M4 8L0 4h8z" fill="red">
    </path>
</svg>
```

Using `uri`:

```
data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='14' height='12' version='1'%3E%3Cpath color='%23FF0000' d='M4 8L0 4h8z' fill='red'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E
```

Example:

```html
<img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='14' height='12' version='1'%3E%3Cpath color='%23FF0000' d='M4 8L0 4h8z' fill='red'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The `fill` and/or `stroke` attribute on the path(s) do not override the CSS styling

What you need to do is override the **CSS** styling itself, this can be done by setting the style property, e.g.

```
<path style="fill:green" ...>
```

Or in **javascript**

```
element.setAttribute('style', 'fill: green');
```

In your response to my comment you mentioned you'd address the 'single path' issue, in order to provide an example for that too here's why and how to fix it.

The `querySelector` method only provides the `first element` (if any) that matches, you want to use the `querySelectorAll` method, which will provide a NodeList containing all matching elements.

```
var paths = doc.querySelectorAll("path"),
    i;

for (i = 0; i < paths.length: ++i) {
    paths[i].setAttribute('style', 'fill:green');
}
```